# Notepad++ - Finding and replacing a special character

Tags: notepad++, special-characters

I would guess this has be answered before, but I am struggling to find anything. A lot of the posts I find are to do with finding FLEC1 (Arabic character) and the suggestions there are to use \u however this doesn't work for me.

I am trying to find and replace all instances of a special character that shows as xB7 in my .xml file.

[image: Example xB7]

I don't actually know what the correct terminology here is for what I'm trying to find, so when I search "special characters" it always ends back with FLEC1...

I believe this is the object in question; http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b7/index.htm

The notepad++ documentation suggests to search for \x then the 2 byte code, but searching for \xB7 doesn't work, neither does \xxB7

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Non_ASCII_characters

Copying and pasting also doesn't work.

Another suggestion was; [^\x00-\x7F]+

However this doesn't operate correctly, it skips singular xB7 codes and out of a string of 9 xB7s in a row it finds the first 4 and the following 4...

Comment: As a workaround, since I needed to get the file out, I substituted the xB7 for .* in a search; Aqua.*Woven.*Front.*Vest.* then replaced it with the correct description. Correcting this on the database was 100 times easier, I just used SQL to replace the character with a space.

Comment: a reproducible example would help

Comment: Have a try with: 1) encode to ANSI; 2) do the replace `\xB7` ==> `whatYou Want`; 3) encode to UTF8

Comment: @Toto please could you submit that as an answer? That worked a treat - ANSI shows the character and subsequently I therefore can use find/replace on it

Comment: @RDKells: Done. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an encoding problem, to solve it, I suggest:

1. Encode the file to ANSI. The character `\xB7` is now displayed `·`
2. Do the replace *via* Replace toolbox. Find: `\xB7`, Replace: `what you want`
3. Encode to UTF-8

Comment: Million $ Answer..!

Comment: make sure that under `Search Mode` you have selected `Extended`